# Codeigniter library is working on localhost but not on web server

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to create a simple installer for my application. I have created a library called **"installer"** which will check database **'database' =>** variable. If database field is not defined it will redirect to install folder. here is my script:

```
<?php
class Installer {
    public function __construct() {
        //get the CI instance
        $CI =& get_instance();
        $CI->load->database();


    //check if databse config set
       if ($CI->db->database == "") {
            redirect('install');
        } else {
        if (is_dir('install')) {
                echo '<i>Plese delete or rename <b>Install</b> folder</i>';
                exit;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have set the library in autoload with database and session library

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session','installer');
```

It works well on my localhost. But when I uploaded it to my web server first time i got 404 error **(because of first letter of the controller file should capital)**, then I have corrected this. But when i got to my url http://example.com/demo (my file in **public_html/demo/** directory) it show some error like

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Uninitialized string offset: 0

Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php

Line Number: 109

Backtrace:

File: /home/xxxxx/public_html/demo/application/controllers/Home.php
Line: 25
Function: __construct

File: /home/xxxxx/public_html/demo/index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php

Line Number: 161

Backtrace:

File: /home/xxxxx/public_html/demo/application/controllers/Home.php
Line: 25
Function: __construct

File: /home/xxxx/public_html/demo/index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once


A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/xxxxx/public_html/demo/system/core/Exceptions.php:272)

Filename: core/Common.php

Line Number: 568

Backtrace:

File: /home/xxxxxx/public_html/demo/application/controllers/Home.php
Line: 25
Function: __construct

File: /home/xxxxxx/public_html/demo/index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once

A Database Error Occurred

Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

Filename: controllers/Home.php

Line Number: 25
```

when i am using it localhost it works well. But when i using this on my server i got this error. My database config file:

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => '',
    'username' => '',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => '',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error "mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO) " which you are getting points to wrong database access detail as you have set "database" library in autoload config and not provided database host,username and password in database config file.

You can try by removing "database" from autoload config and checking database detail by loading database config and checking its value in your  script as follows :

```
  $CI->config->load('database', TRUE);
  $dbConfig = $CI->config->item('database');
```

Comment: I already mentioned this script works well in my wamp server with no error. But problem is on live server.

Comment: I have updated my answer please check it , if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

please set the details of live server here in database.php this should not be blank.

```
'hostname' => '',
'username' => '',
'password' => '',
'database' => '',
```

Comment: If I set all the details then why I need installer library and and extra code for set user submitted database details to database config file?

Answer (score 0):

> CodeIgniter has a config file that lets you store your database connection values (username, password, database name, etc.). The config file is located at application/config/database.php. You can also set database connection values for specific environments by placing database.php it the respective environment config folder.

So you will need to save the database credentials in that file to make it work.

like this:

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost', // The hostname of your database server. Often this is ‘localhost’.
    'username' => 'root', //user name of the database account
    'password' => '', // password
    'database' => 'database_name', // name of the database
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => TRUE,
    'db_debug' => TRUE,
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array()
);
```

Please refer to their manual [here](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/index.html) . Hope it helps.

Comment: Don't want to store, if I set db name to database config file then my library never redirect to install folder. Initially I want it blank so that my library easily know this is new installation. N.b I know how to set databse information to database config file

Comment: what do you mean by "library never redirect to install folder" ?

Comment: "Installer" is a library. and i set it in autoload

Answer (score 0):

edit your `C:\xampp\htdocs\.. application\config\database.php`

```
$active_group = 'default';

$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(

    'dsn'   => '',

    'hostname' => 'localhost',

    'username' => 'root',

    'password' => '',

    'database' => 'your_database_name',

    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',

    'dbprefix' => '',

    'pconnect' => TRUE,

    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),

    'cache_on' => FALSE,

    'cachedir' => '',

    'char_set' => 'utf8',

    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',

    'swap_pre' => '',

    'encrypt' => FALSE,

    'compress' => FALSE,

    'stricton' => FALSE,

    'failover' => array(),

    'save_queries' => TRUE

);
```

Comment: Whilst code only answers may solve the problem, some explanation goes  long way in understanding the solution and how to solve similar issues in the future.